# c# Relative path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, relative-path

Hello I have a program made in Visual Studio in C#. 
In this program I have some pictures that need to be called. And some html files that need to be saved. 
All these files are saved in the map 'mails'. 
At the moment I have the path:

```
 String pad = @"C:\Users\Charlotte\Desktop\proof of concept\mails\";
```

I need this path to be relative so the user of the program can just copy the map mails to wherever he/she wants it and execute the exe of my program and just work with it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `relative` to *what*?

Comment: Sounds like your application is not being installed to a special folder like `Program Files` but runs just from the download location?

Comment: My application is just an exe and an access database that they can place wherever they want it.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What needs to be relative and where does it need to be relative to? What's wrong with the path at the moment?

Comment: To be more specific, do you need this to be relative to the directory where the `.exe` is located, or to the current working directory of the process?

Answer (score 4):

You can use function: **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()** to get the path of current directory instead of telling program the fullpath.

Comment: This helped me a lot when I was trying to use images in my app. Working on my own computer was fine, but when I tried to run it on others, it would brake, due to the fact that they didn't have images in the same directory.  This solved my issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If the user places a file wherever he wants, you need to tell your program where it is aomehow. So if you use OpenFile dialog your path would be:

```
string pad = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

On the other hand if you mean that a path should be relative to your exe file you would use:

```
string pad = Application.StartupPath + "\\mails\\";
```

This will mean that a path is a directory of your exe \mails, but without a name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string path = @"..\..\mails\";
```